# How to get Data Header in eText File Template - BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

I am trying to get a header on my data table, however when I create another group it is repeating the header the same number of times as my data.
So if I have 10 rows of data I get 10 header rows.

I have attached my eText file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1im-iGEIhZuhjlb2XbeD5FoNmQ6y3raz4/view?usp=sharing

Could you please advice me

Answer (score 0):

Have to see your data xml , looks like you also have 10 WORKER nodes in the XML, that could be why it is repeating.

Instead of   WORKER, try  G_1, or whatever is the root of your data xml.

Another option you could try     WORKER[position()=1], so it only prints for the first worker.